# Upload wordpress from localhost to 000webhost

Tags: database, internal-server-error

I want to know how to upload wordpress localhost to server with plugin and filezila i tried many times but failed. When I'm upload wordpress through filezila database cannot connect to the site.

Tell me the whole steps of the before uploading the site from localhost to server.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials regarding this issue and I believe there are also a lot of on site info about this. Please use site search

Comment: Give me a link one of them :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a local WP installation to a server:

**Step 1**
If you are on a host where you can expand an archived file (ie. Cpanel / File Manager) then easiest way is to ZIP or GZIP your entire WP install and upload it to the server, and use File Manager to expand the files and ensure they are placed in the appropriate position (ie. the www root directory usually called www or public_html or httpdocs - check your server details). There are also php based files which you install which will call the appropriate expanders. Either that, if you cannot easily expand an archived file you may wish to do a direct install of WP on from your server via URL or using an inbuilt s/w installer such as Fantastico/Softaculous and then FTP the extra plugin / theme folders and any other files which are additional to a standard WP install individually.

**Step 2**
On your web host, setup your database (MySQL or PostgresSQL), making note of the full DB name, DB user and passwords, and DB table prefix.

**Step 3**
Update your wp-config.php file with the above DB details.

> IMPORTANT: Wordpress chooses to store absolute URL references in the
>   database. As such, if the live web site will use a hostname which is
>   different than what you setup for your local development installation
>   (ie. if you didn't setup the same hostname on your development install
>   as what you will use on the live site) then you will need to change
>   the default absolute URL to the new base URL.

I simply use a text editor to do a find and replace the base ref URL in the SQL database prior to upload.

ie. If I used `http://localhost` but it will be running under `http://www.example.com` when live then I do a simple text find and replace from `http://localhost` with `http://www.example.com`

Comment: thanku v much bro can u give me the video tutorial link?

Comment: @Ahatsham i wouldn't know which one would give you precisely this method as I'm sure some of them will use a plugin like Duplicator to replace Step 3 but this one by Wes Bos is probably a good place to start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk6_lW9INos
Either that or search youtube for "migrating wordpress to a new server" and you'll get plenty.

Comment: Bro I tried many times even 100 times but failed i don't know how :(

Comment: @Ahatsham if you give specifics on the error or what is failing I can help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your time problem is resolved, Actually, I used free hosting at that time.